# Retrofit Android - add header to existing Retrofit object

Tags: android, http-headers, retrofit, retrofit2

Is there a way to add a header to a Retrofit object after it has been created ?

I create a Retrofit object using the Retrofit Builder and then at a later point need to add a certain header to it. The reason for adding it here is that this particular header needs to be added with all requests and its value is dynamic. I would like to avoid having to add this header to every network call separately. Here is how I create it:

```
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(client)
        .baseUrl(String.format(baseUrl, environmentExtension) + "/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create());
builder.build();
```

I would like to add the header to this existing object.

Answer (score 0):

To add `header` to all the requests, you can intercept calls using `Interceptor` and tweak the `request` to add `header`. This has to be done while building `OkHttpClient`

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
builder.addInterceptor(chain -> chain.proceed(chain.request().newBuilder()
                                        .addHeader("key","value").build()));
OkHttpClient client = builder.build();//use this client in retrofit
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way could be creating an `Interceptor` and adding it through the `OkHttpClient's` builder. You can achieve it as following;

```
class HeaderInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    
        val originalRequest = chain.request()
        val requestBuilder = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Key", "Value")
        val request = requestBuilder.build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

```
val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
    connectTimeout(60, SECONDS)
    readTimeout(60, SECONDS)
    writeTimeout(60, SECONDS)
    
    interceptors().add(headerInterceptor)
}.build()
```

You can introduce above interceptor to Retrofit's object as following;

```
Retrofit.Builder().apply {
    baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
    addConverterFactory(Json.asConverterFactory(MEDIA_TYPE_DEFAULT.toMediaType()))
    client(httpClient)
}.build()
```

Comment: I am aware of the intercepts. However, how do I add an interceptor to an existing Retrofit object ?

Comment: @SayedJalilHassan please see my updated answer.

Comment: I know the use of interceptor but I needed a way to modify an existing Retrofit object. This one just creates a new Retrofit object.

Comment: @SayedJalilHassan man, in this way, you can introduce your `OkHttpClient` to `Retrofit Builder`. You can play around with its functions such as `client`, `converterFactory`, etc.